# putting two dash tables side by side in Dash

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I have two dash tables called `dash_table1` and `dash_table2`

On my dash dashboard, I would like to put them side by side.
I have used the following code to show side by side but it is not working.

```
content_tab_1 = html.Div(children = [
                 html.Div(children = [dash_table1, dash_table2], 
                         style={‘vertical-align’:‘center’, ‘horizontal-align’:‘center’})
],
style={‘width’: ‘100%’})
```

But it not still working.

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it. For those of who are looking for the solution, you can use the solution below.

```
html.Div([ 
        html.Div([dash_table1], style={'width': '50%',  'display': 'inline-block'}),
        html.Div([dash_table2], style={'width': '50%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
])
```